# aws cloudwatch logs request.body as "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-cloudwatch, fastify

I am trying to log the body of an api request on Webiny api (they use fastify) but so far cloudwatch is outputting only `"[object Object]"`.

I've tried:

```
console.log(request.body);
console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body));
console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body, null, 2));
```

Could this be how I am making the request?

```
function logData(payload: any) {
  return navigator.sendBeacon('https://example.com/test', payload);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendBeacon` converts the payload to string.

> An ArrayBuffer, a TypedArray, a DataView, a Blob, a string literal or object, a FormData or a URLSearchParams object containing the data to send.

```
navigator.sendBeacon('https://example.com/test', payload)
```

Just need to convert the payload to a string before sending it.

```
JSON.stringify(payload)
```